# Restlet Framework and Spring - Global filter

Tags: java, spring, restlet

I'm having a problem with RESTlet Framework configuration with Spring. I want to have one global filter for all requests and responses. I guess I can use `Filter` class and it's methods `beforeHandle`, `afterHandle` and `setNext` like this:

```
Filter.beforeHandle() -> Router -> Filter.afterHandle()
```

The problem is, that I'm using Spring configured RESTlet and I don't know if the regular Filter will work correctly with SpringRouter from org.restlet.ext.spring package. My current restlet configuration is as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="root" class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringRouter">
        <property name="attachments">
            <map>
                <entry key="/login">
                    <bean class="org.restlet.ext.spring.SpringFinder">
                        <lookup-method name="create"
                                       bean="loginResource" />
                    </bean>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I'm thinking about adding a bean with id root and class that extends class `Filter`, and pass to it as property `next` a bean with id router (which currently is called root). What do you think about this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing Restlet classes from the Spring extension with other one shouldn't be an issue. Spring* classes only provide additional configurability.

Comment: I found it to be completely true.